# Does Stop and Wait for TCP send data with an ACK?

Tags: networking, tcp

Let's say I have a simple TCP connection w/ a client and a server. The client sends some data to the server, and the server sends something back to the client after doing some processing w/ the original data.

I am not 100% on how the flow of packets would work in this situation using a stop and wait protocol. When the client sends the original data to the server, does the server send an ACK and the new data at the same time (same packet?), or are these sent separately?

From examples I have seen online, I'm not able to understand fully when a server sends data back to a client in relation to when it sends an ACK.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server has some data already queued up to send back to the client, it can use [TCP piggybacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piggybacking_(data_transmission)) so that (the server's ack of the client's packet) and (some of the server's reply data) share a single packet.  That makes the protocol a bit more efficient, as fewer packets have to be sent back to the client.

If the server doesn't have any of its own application-level data to send back at the time it wants to send the ACK packet, then the ACK packet will go back to the client as a stand-alone packet.  (In a stop-and-wait protocol, the server probably wouldn't have any application-level data ready to send back yet, since the ACK is supposed to go back to the client as soon as the client's packet is received, and in this case the server app doesn't generate any data until after it has done its processing of the received client data)

Comment: So do you just have to have some agreed on format for the packet so both the client/server know how to see an ACK?

Comment: TCP ACK packets are handled internally by the TCP stack, and are not visible to the application code at all.  Of course you can implement your own application-level ACKs as well, if you want to, but it's not necessary to do so.

Comment: Keep in mind that when using TCP, the user programs at either end of the TCP connection should not be thinking in terms of packets.  TCP simulates a byte-stream (e.g. similar to a bi-directional pipe) and hides all of the per-packet details behind the stream-of-bytes abstraction.

Comment: I see. So we send the ACK right after the packet is received.  So for stop and wait we will likely send the ACK by itself, then do some processing on the server side and then send the server data to the client. 

1 more question: Since I have the server sending data to the client, I should have the client send ACKs to the server as well, correct?

Comment: I would say:  your programs should not explicitly send any ACKs unless you have a concrete reason for doing so.  The TCP stack(s) of the two computers will automatically send ACKs at the appropriate times, so there's no need for your code to do so.  All the client program needs to do is send its request data, then wait for the reply data from the server.  All the server program needs to do is wait for the request data, and then send the reply data.